# How can this effect (line breaks) be achieved with CSS and/or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, newline

Right now i am using multiple heading tags and a css class to achieve the effect shown in the image below, Is there any way to achieve this by using just a single heading/line and css?

Current Code :

```
<h2 class="heading">Hi guys, How can i achieve this effect using just a single</h2>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<h2 class="heading">line of text and css. Right now i am using</h2>
<h2 class="heading">multiple &lt;h2&gt; tags and a css class to achieve this effect.</h2>
<h2 class="heading">Is it possible to achieve this only with css or do i have to use Javascript as well?</h2>
```

Expected Code

```
<h2 class="heading">Hi guys, How can i achieve this effect using just a single line of text and css. Right now i am using multiple &lt;h2&gt; tags and a css class to achieve this effect. Is it possible to achieve this only with css or do i have to use Javascript as well?</h2>
```

The main problem with this according to me is, I cannot make it responsive without decreasing font size, padding, etc which i don't want.

And even if i make it responsive i cannot add line breaks wherever i want without using other tags or javascript.

How did you guys get around this?

[image: How can i achieve this effect using a single heading/any tag and with css]

Comment: What makes the first line break sooner than the last line?

Comment: Without extra html/css, this isn't going to happen because each line breaks at a different width and somewhat arbitrarily. I don't know how you would make this text responsive if a) you wanted to keep the same text on each line while b) not changing the font size. Javascript should not be necessary at all.

Comment: I want the line style to be same the text/words can be in different lines, But if i use <br>, <span> tags i dont think it will be possible.

Comment: "if i make it responsive i cannot add line breaks wherever i want" - this statement is correct. Forget about manually controlling line breaks if you intend to use this design in a fluid layout, just let the heading flow naturally.

Comment: What do you mean by responsive?

Comment: @rmarimon checkout my comment on Alexis Pigeon's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one, of the tons of solutions

```
<h2 class="heading">
    <span>Hi guys, How can i achieve this effect using just a single</span>
    <span>line of text and css. Right now i am using</span>
    <span>multiple &lt;h2&gt; tags and a css class to achieve this effect.</span>
    <span>Is it possible to achieve this only with css or do i have to use Javascript as well?</span>
    <span class="clear"></span>
</h2>
```

with this styles in `<head>`

```
<style type="text/css">
    h2.heading {
        background:#0f0;
        padding:2px;
        float:left;
    }

    h2.heading span {
        clear:left;
        display:block;
        float:left;
        background:#fff;
        padding:1px;
        margin:1px;
    }

    h2.heading .clear {
        clear:left;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        float:none;
    }
</style>
```

EDIT: second variant

```
<style type="text/css">
    h2.heading {
        background:#0f0;
        padding:2px;
        display:inline-block;
        font-size:20px;
    }

    h2.heading span {
        background:#fff;
        padding:1px;
        margin:1px;
        line-height:30px;
    }
</style>
```

with this markup

```
<div style="width:300px;">
    <h2 class="heading">
        <span>Hi guys, How can i achieve this effect using just a single line of text and css. Right now i am using multiple &lt;h2&gt; tags and a css class to achieve this effect. Is it possible to achieve this only with css or do i have to use Javascript as well?</span>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This is kinda similar to what i have done, But we cannot make it responsive right?

Answer (score 1):

No need of CSS or JavaScript, just use the `<br>` tag.

```
<h2 class="heading">
Hi guys, How can i achieve this effect using just a single
<br> 
line of text and css. Right now i am using 
<br>
multiple &lt;h2&gt; tags and a css class to achieve this effect.
<br>
Is it possible to achieve this only with css or do i have to use Javascript as well?
</h2>
```

Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: This is little better, But can web make this responsive?

Comment: What do you mean by *responsive*?

Comment: By responsive i mean 1. Either just enter text without br or span tags and somehow add this new line style and depending on the browser width the width of this heading will automatically change and everything else will remain same. And even if we somehow achieve this 2. Ability to place line breaks wherever i want without messing its default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of solved the problem. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/7nafE/ (remove the div to see the responsivness)

HTML:

```
<span class="heading">Hi guys, How can i achieve this effect using just a single line of text and css. Right now i am using multiple &lt;h2&gt; tags and a css class to achieve this effect. Is it possible to achieve this only with css or do i have to use Javascript as well?</h2>
```

Same as your HTML except that I used a span instead of h2

And css:

```
.heading {
        background: white;
        line-height:2em;
        padding: 0.3em;;
    }

    body { /*not really neccessary to show, but anyway*/
        background: limegreen;
        font-family: verdana;
        color: #999999}
```

Problem with that is that there are no paddings to the left and right of the text.
And also. you can't get your line breaks where you want. It is all up to which container you place it in. It is, if you asked me, just good because that makes it responsive in a way a `<br />` or something like that wouldn't do.

Comment: Yeah, you did solve the problem but as soon as i use h2 tag instead of the span tag you used at the beginning, it doesn't work... But i dont think there is any other way (CSS)...

Comment: H2 are block elements, and span are inline elements. If you really want to use H2, insert: display: inline; to the class .headings and it will work